# ActionScript: symbol movie clipt no looping

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have symbol type movie clip with name `xmovie`

how to make this symbol not looping every time it finish animate?

is there any action script can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can put a `stop();` statement on the last frame of the `MovieClip`.

You can also use `addFrameScript` (no need to modify the flash library) :

```
xmovie.addFrameScript(test.totalFrames-1, function() : void {
    xmovie.stop();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways :

1) You can use the timeline to put a stop(); on your last frame.

2) You can use actionscript :

```
yourMovieClip.addFrameScript(yourMovieClip.totalFrames-1, function() {
       yourMovieClip.stop();
});
```